# Building customised Linux image using Yocto project with Qt stack

Tags: linux, qt, embedded

i'm fairly new to Linux and currently trying to build a customized Linux image using Yocto Project and also planning to add Qt stack into the image. I've a 2 questions:

1. When building customized Linux image with Qt stack, do I need to build a customized Linux image using Yocto Project first, and then link Qt stack; or need to build a Linux image with Qt stack embedded in it?
2. What is the development time required to build a customized Linux image with Qt stack using Yocto Project?

Thank you!

Comment: Some confusion here. Yocto through bitbake can provide a complete Linux kernel, with DTBs, u-boot and RootFS for your target. It can also exctract complete toolchain/SDK based on your target. What you want, I guess, is a recipe that add qt libs to your final rootFS and SDK. For example: the  standard meta recipe **qt4e-demo-image**

Comment: Hi LPs, indeed. I'm a little consumed. I need a recipe that adds qt libs to my final rootFD and SDK. My chipset is also not in the reference images built by Yocto. So is there like a easy-to-read manual to get a customised Linux image with qt lib embedded into it?

Comment: An _easy-to-read_ is quite difficult to find. Is an hard matter. What I can suggest is to start from an existant recipe and, at least, add qt4 recipe to that. This will add the qt4 to your final rootFS and SDK. For reference you can look at [BitBake manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html)

Comment: I see. What if i've an existing toolchain from the SDK as well as a pre-compiled linux image, rootfs & Uboot. Are there any good manuals to guide me how to add Qt lib into my rootfs, and then compile into images (linux kernel; rootfs with qt and Uboot) ?

Comment: You cannot find a so specific guide. What I can suggest you is to compile a qt recipe using bitbake and use qmake, libs and headers exported to update your SDK and your target.